# using a dependency injection for 'URLSession' causes a "BAD ACCESS" infinite loop error

Tags: ios, mocking, swift4, nsurlsession, exc-bad-access

Currently I'm adding a dependency injection into my code so it can be unit tested with a mock 'URLSession'.  I used this article as reference: [Guide to network unit testing swift](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/the-complete-guide-to-network-unit-testing-in-swift-db8b3ee2c327) This is what the code looks like (minus the mock data):

```
// Protocol for MOCK/Real
protocol URLSessionProtocol {
    typealias DataTaskResult = (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void

    func dataTask(with request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping DataTaskResult) -> URLSessionDataTaskProtocol
}

protocol URLSessionDataTaskProtocol {
    func resume()
}

//MARK: HttpClient Implementation
class HttpClient {

    typealias completeClosure = ( _ data: Data?, _ error: Error?)->Void

    private let session: URLSessionProtocol

    init(session: URLSessionProtocol) {
        self.session = session

    }

    func get( url: URL, callback: @escaping completeClosure ) {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            callback(data, error)
        }
        task.resume()
    }

}

//MARK: Conform the protocol
extension URLSession: URLSessionProtocol {
    func dataTask(with request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping DataTaskResult) -> URLSessionDataTaskProtocol

    {
        return dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: completionHandler) as URLSessionDataTaskProtocol

    }
}

extension URLSessionDataTask: URLSessionDataTaskProtocol {}
```

I'm trying to run it with "URLSession.shared" first to make sure it runs in a real environment:

```
let HTTP = HttpClient(session: URLSession.shared)

HTTP.get(url: URL(string: "https://sampleUrl")!) { (data, error) in}
```

The error "BAD ACCESS" occurs here:

```
extension URLSession: URLSessionProtocol {
    func dataTask(with request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping DataTaskResult) -> URLSessionDataTaskProtocol

    {
        return dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: completionHandler) as URLSessionDataTaskProtocol//This is where the error happens

    }
}
```

I can see in the debug navigator `URLSession.dataTask(with:completionHandler)` is repeated over and over again until it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to fix this issue, had to rewrite the protocol for Swift4:

```
protocol URLSessionProtocol {
    func dataTask(with url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTaskProtocol
}
```